# DataSnap - how to change SELECT query to show different data?

Tags: delphi, datasnap, tclientdataset

In DataSnap, I have a server and client. In the client, I use this code to show data in a `TDBGrid`:

```
ClientDataSet1.CommandText := 'SELECT * from table_name WHERE autoid = 10';
ClientDataSet1.Open;
ClientDataSet1.Refresh;
```

But when I want to change this, the `TDBGrid` is not showing different data, it still shows data from my first code:

```
ClientDataSet1.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE autoid = 1';
ClientDataSet1.Open;
ClientDataSet1.Refresh;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You have to start formatting your posts properly **and** to include which data types your variables are of! And use more/proper tags, like [TClientDataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tclientdataset)!

Comment: Your TDataSetProvider.Options must have poAllowCommandText checked. You must also ClientDataSet1.Close and then ClientDataSet1.Open. Refresh has no effect.

Comment: @FreddieBell that should be posted as an answer instead of a comment.